# JavaMail Read Messages

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Ok, so two questions. I'm able to access and read my new email inbox using javamail but:

1. If i try to read the messages already found by javamail, javamail seems not to be able to read them again.
2. Javamail cant read messages with numbers in the subject.

How can I make it so that both of these are possible?

Thank you

UPDATE:
Fixed question 1, I was using gmail and the setting needs to be configured so that the messages can be seen by JavaMail once opened. Still stuck on the second question though :(

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific with your question. You are using a POP3 provider? an IMAP one?

I use javamail and have processed millions of real world mails many of which certainly contain numbers in the subject, so I suspect it's not a javamail problem.

If you think so, add more data and stack traces etc